# Why my C++ program crash when convert lambda to function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, lambda, crash

I tried to convert a lambda function into a function pointer, compile OK, but runtime crash(VC2013). This lambda function is simply to delete a pointer, like this:

```
typedef void(*pf)(void*);
struct M
{
    ~M(){ printf("dtor\n"); }
};
int main(void)
{
    M *p = new M;
    auto f = [](M*p){delete p; };
    pf p1 = (pf)&f;
    (*p1)(p);
    return 0;
}
```

[/code]

The crash seems to happen within CRT, unable to debug by myself. Where my crash come from? Thanks a lot

Comment: `(pf)&f;` is dangerous , to ensure that the cast can be performed safely use `static_cast`. Using that you will get and error basically saying that that the type of `f` is not a pointer to a function. => undefined behavior

Comment: Don not cast, unless you know what you do: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]

Comment: Why using pointer-to-function ? C++11 offer many other kind of other way of storing pointer to something callable

Comment: "I tried to convert a lambda function into a function pointer": No, you tried to convert a *pointer* to a lambda function into a function pointer. (And when the compiler said that you can't, you didn't listen but inserted a cast instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. Non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers, pointers to lambdas cannot. Get rid of address-of operator.
2. Type of function lambda represents is `void(*)(M*)`. `pf` is `void(*)(void*)`. They are not compatible! Either make lambda take `void*` or change `fp` to take `M*` argument.
3. C-casts silently do the wrong thing. You do not need one if everything else is correct, implicit conversion is enough.

Following code will work:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct M
{
    ~M(){ printf("dtor\n"); }
};

typedef void(*pf)(M*);

int main(void)
{
    M *p = new M;
    auto f = [](M*p){delete p; };
    pf p1 = f;
    (*p1)(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting objects through `void*` is going to get you into trouble.

1. Change the type of argument to f to be `void f(M*)`
2. Don't write code like this it will get you in the end

Here's your code that works on gcc 4.8

```
#include <cstdio>

class M; //forward dec
typedef void(*pf)(M*);

struct M
{
    ~M(){ printf("dtor\n"); }
};



int main(void)
{
    M *p = new M;
    auto f = [](M*p){delete p; };
    pf p1 = f;
    (*p1)(p);
    return 0;
}
```